# Помогите составить регулярку для поиска

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Нужна регулярка для поика в notepad++

пример:
Есть строка.

> Feel free to stop on by, or contact us about your needs. We look forward to hearing from you!

Программа синонимайзер поддчёркивает возможные синонимы и предлагает замены.

> {Feel free to|Twenty-four hours a day|Do|Then|You can} stop on by, or {contact us|e mail us|call us|e-mail us|email us} about {your needs|your requirements|your preferences|the needs you have|your family needs}. {We look forward|Good quality} to {hearing from|talking with|listening to|meeting up with} you!

мне надо удалить первое вложение `{****|` я так понимаю будет так найти `{.*?|` заменить `_пусто_` потом, то что в центре, оставить и удалить всё что после,  и вот на этом загвоздка,  как найти строки начинающиеся с `|` (внутри вложения которого встречаются от 1-4 разделителей   `|`)  и закрывается `}`  Как выглядит код?

Comment: Вам нужно второе совпадение? Если да, то вот регулярка:  

    \{[^\|]++\|([^\|]++)

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/230900/php-разбить-строку-на-массив

Answer (score 3):

```
\{[^|}]++\|([^|}]++)(?:\|[^|}]++)*\}
```

Это регулярное выражение выберет второй вариант из предложенных синонимов.

Проверить работу можно [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/wK6sH2/2)

Чтобы сделать замену по тексту, в поле для поиска вбейте упомянутое выше регулярное выражение `\{[^|}]++\|([^|}]++)(?:\|[^|}]++)*\}`, а в поле для замены `$1`.

Ваш текст после замены будет выглядеть так:

> Twenty-four hours a day stop on by, or e mail us about your
>   requirements. Good quality to talking with you!